# Manual copypasting apps for backup

Tags: macos, backup, applications, copy-paste, migration

I just switched from a full Windows+Google ecosystem to a full Apple ecosystem and I am finding my way quite easily.

Still, i have to understand a couple of things about how data is stored, read and moved in macOS.

Most notably: I saw that 99% of apps install through moving the .app bundle to Applications.

Is it safe to assume that I could theoretically backup and copy all my apps (maybe even programmatically) to an external storage and pasting them back on any other (compatible) macOS system?

If so, except for local data specific to each application, would that work or is there some hidden magic done by macOS in background to "install" the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the world of Mac! I'm glad your transition has been easy.

Yes, all Mac apps exist as a 'bundle' - really a special folder whose contents are hidden. Any app that you install by dragging to the Applications folder can be copied and pasted to the Applications folder of any other Mac.

However:

- apps bought on the Mac App Store are linked to your AppleID -- you may be asked to sign in to your account on the new Mac to use them, or to update them.
- some third-party apps may have licence codes, seat-limited authorization etc.

If an app is installed not by dragging, but with an installer package (.pkg file), it likely does install or configure things in other places that are essential for it to work properly. You may want to archive these packages (though you can nearly always download them, or a newer version, again).

As for backups: I'd suggest using macOS's Time Machine feature for backups. This will backup everything except the OS itself: apps, configuration files, user data, etc, etc.

Time Machine is easy to configure and easy to restore files from. So you don't have to worry about choosing what to backup and what not to backup.

You can import ('migrate') data from a Time Machine backup onto any new Mac you own in the future.

However, if you want to copy apps and configuration data wholesale to multiple Macs, then there are tools for cloning and imaging the entire disk, or otherwise 'managing' devices, though these process are more complex than once they were, due to security.